# Возможно ли перехватить клик на верхнем View и передать нижнему View?

Tags: android, view

Возможно ли разместить над одним `View` другое прозрачное `View` для перехвата кликов? То есть нужно, чтобы при клике верхнее `View` вызывало наш `OnClickListener`, а затем передавало этот клик нижнему `View`.

Поясню для чего это нужно. Пытаюсь вставить в приложение рекламу от StartApp, но у них не работает `setOnClickListener`. Писал им, они сказали, что это глюк, и обещали исправить. Но уже вторая неделя к концу подходит, а они так ничего и не исправили. Возможно ли разместить над их баннером пустое `View`, повесить на него свой `listener` и чтобы оно передавало этот клик ниже?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

1) Разместить их блок и свой слой в RalteiveLayou или FramLayout. Свой слой поверх их.

2) При клике по своему слою вызывать для их слоя `perfomClick()`.

3) Всё.

Comment: Такой подход не работает: клик на моем слое обрабатывается нормально, а по их баннеру клик не отрабатывается. Вероятно, они используют не OnClickListener. Есть ли другие способы передать клик на нижний слой?

Comment: Можно попробовать послать их слою два события подряд: onDown и onUp key events

Comment: А что при таком раскладе нужно указать в параметрах int keyCode и KeyEvent event?